# How can i remove product gallery " fotorama__stage" class height?

Tags: magento2, gallery-image, product-detail-page

I am facing issue of image height on product details page gallery.

If i remove **fotorama__stage** class height from inspect element then its work fine.

Please check below image.

[image]

How can i remove product gallery **fotorama__stage** class height ? In which file ?

Comment: Do you want to adjust the image height?

Comment: @RajMohanR no i just want to remove height from fotorama__stage class

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: @magefms i am using my custom theme and my parent theme is luma

Comment: you can add your custom css then apply changes to height

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix, You can add custom CSS where you can define and apply changes on `fotorama__stage` height.

Create your custom CSS file, `custom.css`

put this css at below path

> app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/web/css/custom.css

After that specify the path of your css in below file:

> app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

add following in this file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

In your `custom.css` put this code

```
.catalog-product-view .product.media .fotorama__stage{
    height: 0px !important;
}
```